# Select 2 characters after a particular substring in javascript

Tags: javascript

We have a string ,

```
var str = "Name=XYZ;State=TX;Phone=9422323233";
```

Here in the above string we need to fetch only the State value i.e TX. That is 2 characters after the substring **State=**

Can anyone help me implement it in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split()` the string into array and then find the index of the array element having `State` string. Using that index get to that element and again `.split()` it and get the result. Try this way,

```
var str = "Name=XYZ;State=TX;Phone=9422323233";

var strArr = str.split(';');

var index = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
    if(strArr[i].match("State")){
        index = i;
    }
}

console.log(strArr[index].split('=')[1]);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/54nfqfg7/)

Comment: Thanks. However the State= position will be different sometimes. That is we may get the string as "Name=XYZ;Phone=9422323233;State=TX";

Comment: @Skyrim, Then you need to find the index of the `State` after using `split()` on it. And then get the value of `State`. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns the position of the string in the other string.

Using this index you can find the next two characters

javascript something like

```
 var n = str.indexOf("State=");
```

then use slice method

like

```
var res = str.slice(n,n+2);
```

another method is :

use `split function`

```
 var newstring=str.split("State=");
```

then

```
var result=newstring.substr(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var str1 = "Name=XYZ;State=TX;Phone=9422323233";
var n = str1.search("State");
n=n+6;
var res = str1.substr(n, 2);
```

The result is in the variable `res`, no matter where `State` is in the original string.

Comment: what about this string `var str = "Name=XYZ;Phone=9422323233;State=TXBBP";`? It won't work with your code I guess.

Comment: It will bring out "TX" only, because is selecting only two characters.

Is the state code of variable length?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way out is by slicing and splitting

```
var str = "Name=XYZ;State=TX;Phone=9422323233";
var findme = str.split(';')[1];
var last2 = findme.slice(-2);
alert(last2);
```

*Need more help? Let me know*

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to get what you're after:

```
var str = "Name=XYZ;State=TX;Phone=9422323233"
```

Using *match*:

```
var match = str.match(/State=.{2}/);
var state = match? match[0].substring(6) : '';
console.log(state);
```

Using *replace*:

```
var state = str.replace(/^.*State=/,'').substring(0,2);
console.log(state);
```

Using *split*:

```
console.log(str.split('State=')[1].substring(0,2));
```

There are many other ways, including constructing an object that has name/value pairs:

```
var obj = {};
var b = str.split(';');
var c;

for (var i=b.length; i; ) {
  c = b[--i].split('=');
  obj[c[0]] = c[1];
}

console.log(obj.State);
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Nice answer, i am also give an answer to this question . but your answer is so nice, it shows how to approach a problem in different ways .

Comment: who knows if `State` will always have a `value` with `length` of `2`? You last solution is your best one.

Comment: @AshadShanto—"*That is 2 characters after the substring State=*". The object method addresses that aspect too.

Comment: @AshadShanto you are right, but with a simple validation he can do that